# Boot full of older images - need to remove for updates

Tags: boot, drive

Confused and new to linux.  Know there are older images not being used.  Know the current version is 53.  Know files in boot:

```
abi-3.13.0-32-generic         initrd.img-3.13.0-53-generic
abi-3.13.0-43-generic         lost+found
abi-3.13.0-44-generic         memtest86+.bin
abi-3.13.0-52-generic         memtest86+.elf
abi-3.13.0-53-generic         memtest86+_multiboot.bin
config-3.13.0-32-generic      System.map-3.13.0-32-generic
config-3.13.0-43-generic      System.map-3.13.0-43-generic
config-3.13.0-44-generic      System.map-3.13.0-44-generic
config-3.13.0-52-generic      System.map-3.13.0-52-generic
config-3.13.0-53-generic      System.map-3.13.0-53-generic
grub                  vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-43-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-44-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-44-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-52-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-52-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-53-generic
```

Don't know what is safe to delete so I can do updates. Please help.  Thank you.  Added: Boot partition configured as installed, I did not set it 
(I believe) it is a 1tb drive plenty of free space.

Comment: I usually retain the last two. I never need them (well, seldom need them and only if I broke something by being me) and delete the rest. So, I'd leave all the `abi` the last two `config` leave `grub` and then leave the last two `initrd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From you question I am assuming you do not have a lot of experience with Ubuntu. The easiest way then and the one I prefer is using Ubuntu-Tweak. But please keep in mind it is not an available from official Ubuntu repositories and can be installed using a third-party PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

You can choose to delete which of the previous versions you want to delete, even all of them. I would recommend it for new users since it would not let you delete the current kernel version you are using. And it is wiser to keep 2-3 kernel versions in case you want to use a previous version if something goes wrong with the latest one installed.

Comment: Took time to realize it was GUI interface vs. cmd line.  Once I ran it I could retain the latest 2 and delete the rest.  Worked like a charm.   Then updated .  Thank you this was the easiest by far.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T),
then type *(this is an EXAMPLE - and skip the \'es if you put it on a single line)*:

```
sudo apt-get purge \
linux-headers-3.16.0-51 \
linux-headers-3.16.0-51-generic \
linux-image-3.16.0-51-generic  \
linux-image-extra-3.16.0-51-generic
```

`dpkg --list | grep ' linux-'` will display what your machine has installed. Just don't remove what you're running (`uname -a` will tell that)